# Steady flow of a fluid observed in different reference frames

Tags: fluid-dynamics

My question is that ,is it possible for a fluid to have steady motion in one frame and non steady motion in another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the fluid has an [inertial  frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_frame_of_reference) where it has a steady motion, then one can make a transformation to an inertial frame where it is at rest, a frame moving with the fluid.

If by "non steady motion" you mean that the velocity of the flow changes with time and space, the answer is no, the flow cannot be described within one inertial frame. [See here.](https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Electrical_Engineering/Electro-Optics/Book%3A_Continuum_Electromechanics_(Melcher)/02%3A_Electrodynamic_Laws_Approximations_and_Relations/2.05%3A_Transformations_between_Inertial_Frames)

Comment: But the motion of a fluid near the wing of an airplane is steady when observed from the plane's frame but unsteady from ground frame. How do you explain this?https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streamlines,_streaklines,_and_pathlines#Frame_dependence

Comment: @Arjun  I explain it in that the changes in time and space are the same for the observer and  the flow, as if one body, ( if it is really steady) but a continuous different inertial frame (time dependent instantaneously) is needed to model it, so there is no "at rest" frame.